# evalin with variable - MatLab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do something like `evalin('base','mat(x)', 4)`, where mat is a matrix in my main script, and x is a variable in the function I'm running this from. How can I use the `x` variable in there?

Comment: Is it correct to use that last `4` as an argument to `evalin`?

Comment: You're right, the `4` shouldn't be there. I was thinking of `assignin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
evalin('base',['mat(' num2str(x) ')'])
```

This substitutes `x` for the value it has in your function, and uses that value to build the string that is passed to `evalin`.

Comment: use 'caller' instead of 'base', more useful for future use.